# Give coordinate distance of every item to a particular item

Tags: sqlite, ms-access

I'd like to provide a list of all items that are closest to a particular item, and give the document numbers that they appear on.

So, for a table, with X and Y being coordinates

```
Item            X      Y
Apple           0      2
Orange          1      3
Pear            0      4
Orange          1      3
```

I want to return something like

```
Item       Closest Items         Distance
Apple         Orange                (SQRT(2))            
Apple         Orange                 (SQRT(2))                   
etc
```

My hang up is the distance part and how it would filter the smallest item string to the top.

So far I have

```
SELECT Item, T1.Item as [Closest Item],
(SQRT( (Here's where I get lost on the selection of subsequent coordinates))
```

This is currently done in MS Access, but I have python / SQLite library at my disposal too. Would prefer Access for easier automation.

EDIT: Made it simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there should be a primary key in the table like an `id` so the table looks like this:

```
id   Item            X      Y
1    Apple           0      2
2    Orange          1      3
3    Pear            0      4
4    Orange          1      3
```

Now you can do a self join and calculate the distance with the formula:

```
distance = square root((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)
```

like this:

```
SELECT t.Item, tt.Item AS [Closest Items],
  SQR((t.X - tt.X) * (t.X - tt.X)+ (t.Y - tt.Y) * (t.Y - tt.Y)) AS Distance
FROM tablename AS t INNER JOIN tablename AS tt
ON t.id <> tt.id
ORDER BY t.Item, tt.Item, SQR((t.X - tt.X) * (t.X - tt.X)+ (t.Y - tt.Y) * (t.Y - tt.Y))
```